# How to line up the subject in a series of photos?

Tags: software

I have a series of photographs each taken about 3 days apart over 4 months, there are about 60 images in total. I'd like to be able to present them as an animated gif but without the subject seeming to jump around when the picture was taken from a slightly different angle. Is there software which can help?

I have access to Photoshop/Lighroom.

Comment: Also relevant: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/49581/9161

Answer (score 0):

I personally haven't done this myself but I found a website where someone describes a way to do it: http://davecornthwaite.tumblr.com/post/64763254999/how-to-create-a-daily-photo-project-video.

To ensure your face is pretty much in the same position you could use photoshop and draw guidelines at mouth and eye level and the base of your chin.
You can then use the vertical and horizontal guides to line up the side, top and bottom of your face for each photograph.

This way you would have to work through all the photographs one by one.
I can't think of a software that would do it automatically.