# What methods exist for time-lapse photography? (Over multiple days)

Tags: timelapse, panorama

So, I've been trying to get into taking time-lapse photos.  I already have a number of sample images of melting snow, in panorama.  (I'd like to do all four seasons somewhere.)

My question is: what methods exist of blending photos together?  I could simply do averages, but I've learned from taking  [Harvard CS50x](https://www.edx.org/course/cs50s-introduction-to-computer-science) that the way in which panoramas are made is that the computer finds the shortest distance between the edges of the photos and stitches them together.  Is there a way to do something similar to fade completely different images together?

Are there any well known techniques or software for doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking to make a single resulting image, or are you creating a time-lapse video?

Comment: More of a time-lapse video.   I'm not quite sure how snow-melt would be represented in a single image, but I'm open to dieas

Comment: Two things: 1. video is off-topic at Photo-SE. [video.se] exists for video production. 2. Open-ended, list-oriented, idea-generating style questions don't work well here, or almost any Stack Exchange. Is there a specific problem you're having? What have you tried, and how has that not worked out?

Answer (score 2):

The starters the easiest is simply to assemble images into a video. This will already give you a time-lapse. Any tool that can create a video from images can do this. `ffmpeg` is a popular free utility with lots of options but will give you something without much trouble. See [this SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/q/249101/69544) for details and other options.

The second level is to align images to reduce shake. Shooting from a tripod is really important as it minimizes shake but it is possible that the framing shifted during a long time-lapse. In this case you can use either a tool to align images before merging (such as align_image_stack as [detailed here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/12777/1620)) or use the *stabilize* feature available in many video editing software.

With long running time-lapse, you may have huge intervals between frames which causes the final video to be jerky due to the slow capture rate or if you render it at a reasonable speed (24+ FPS), it may be too short for your liking or too fast for viewers. For such cases, you need to look at *Motion Interpolation* which creates in between frames. This is usually a feature of higher-end video editing software but I'm not up to date, so you have to search online to find out which current ones offer this feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the images directly to video frames using something like this: http://www.candylabs.com/videovelocity You generally need a lot of images for this to be successful.

You can use a slide show program like Proshow Gold to fade each image into the next image. This works best if you only have a few images to work with. http://www.photodex.com/proshow/gold

Answer (score 1):

There's this handy software called [FantaMorph](https://www.fantamorph.com/). I guess this is the *fade* you're refering to.

Capture-wise, this is what I'd do:

1. set camera on a tripod in a secure location (meaning no wind could knock it over)
2. Set up your interval remote timer. (not sure about community standards regarding linking to amazon/ebay, but I'm sure you're one google away of finding out what one is and what the cost is).
3. set it and forget it
4. Stitch it together into a movie using any software you like.