# What is it called when you put a sequence of photos together to show an event?

Tags: photoshop, terminology, collage, montage

I just been taking photos of a demolition of a building and I am trying to remember what the technique is called when you go in Photoshop and put a sequence of photos together to show the event.

What is this called, and how would I do it? Are there tricks in Photoshop or other software that make it easy?

Comment: Hi boburger. Welcome to the site! I'm not quite clear on what you mean — do you mean a single final image with multiple exposures over time [like this](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12233), or images combined side-by-side in a collage?

Comment: A collage is what I mean but like in a strip of photos so it shows the demolitions course of action . So if you looked at the most left picture it would be a building and if you followed the pictures to the right side it would just be rubble.

Comment: Are you looking for something like "film strip"? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhLbGleU-iY

Answer (score 8):

From what you describe I think the word you are looking for is **montage**. This is a term borrowed from the movies, where it refers to a set of short sequences edited together to show an event.

The classic example is a 'training montage' where the previously hapless hero undergoes a lifetime's training in 30 seconds (usually to music) before emerging a master.

A photographic montage is similar - a sequence of separate shots, put together into one image to tell a story.

To make one in Photoshop, you just need to create a new image big enough to hold the number of shots in the sequence, open those shots, then drag and drop them into the new image. You might want to leave a border around each image so factor that in when you calculate the size of the image.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe the word you're looking for is **triptych** ?

Comment: Have you got any hints on how to make one?

Comment: Welcome to photo.stackexchange @sam. I am not sure the OP was specifically thinking about a triptcyh, but that is a *great* idea for a building's demolition! I'm imagining a large, beautiful image of the building in its full glory in the center, with pictures of the demolition and a debris-filled lot on either side -- wow!

Answer (score 4):

**A slideshow is when images are shown one after the other**, either advancing manually or automatically after a short interval. Images appear still but may have some kind of animation called a *transition* between them.

**A time-lapse is when images are stringed together at regular frame-rate** (5 to 60 FPS, typically) into a video. The effect is a scene advancing at an accelerated pace compared to the actual event.

One could make it reverse and take a quick event and slow it down, but that is not usually called a time-lapse although it can be done the same way. You can also shoot video and speed it up (skipping frames) or slow it down (slower frame-rate or interpolating intermediate frames). It does not even have to be done uniformly. This is usually called a **time-warp**.

Answer (score 1):

A group of photos that tell a story is called a **Narrative or a photo essay** . This is almost always an assignment in any photography coarse. It can be very subjective and up to the photographer but the viewer should be able to recognize that the group of photos are telling a story.  While this might no be  specifically what you are asking,  it is the answer to   "What is it called when you put a sequence of photos together to show an event"

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility of an answer could be: kinestasis - a rapidly-moving montage technique set to music. Like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=viyufRQKlto

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to remember what the technique is called when you go in Photoshop and put a sequence of photos together to show the event. What is this called?

This could be a diptych (2 images), triptych (3 images) or [polyptych](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/polyptychs) (4 or more images). Example:

[image]

> and how would I do it? Are there tricks in Photoshop or other software that make it easy?

See [How do I tile pictures in a grid?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/18373/9282).