# How can I create a double exposure image in Photoshop?

Tags: photo-editing, multiple-exposure, photoshop-cs5

I have two photos I want to use to create a double exposure image. How can I do this with Photoshop CS5?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I combine multiple exposures for action shots?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12233/how-do-i-combine-multiple-exposures-for-action-shots)

Comment: @mattdm, If the OP wants a traditional "Multiple exposure" effect, not a "clone" effect, that question's not a duplicate, as nobody's demoing/mentioning transparency between layers.

Comment: Use layers. There are tons of tutorials online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the double-exposure effect you're going for is the traditional multiple-exposure look of images overlaid on each other, you can simply place each image on a separate layer and adjust the transparency of the top layer(s) or multiply the layers.

If the double-exposure effect you're going for is the one-image-inside-the-head of a portrait, you place the portrait on top of the background. Then
select and erase the bits that aren't the head on that layer (most of the video tutorial shows the various selection tools you can use). Then, with the same selection in place, do the same erasure on the background layer. Then multiply the layers (alternatively, you could adjust the transparency of the top layer).

Alex Wise had a detailed video tutorial with PS CS5 on his blog here:
http://www.alexwisephotography.net/blog/2014/05/05/how-to-create-a-double-exposure-in-photoshop/