# How to show the differences between two images in one combined image in Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop, multiple-exposure

I have two images of a watch, with the watch placed in the same position, but the second-hand in two different positions. And I want to show up the same second-hand in two different positions in the final image. I mean can I do it without playing with the opacity sliders? Because I want to show up the second-hands very strongly in the final image.

**File→Scripts→Load Files into Stack...** or **File→Scripts→Statistics...** with auto-align, doesn't work in this case since Photoshop can't automatically align the the images as they are heavily paralleled.

Comment: I cannot understand what do you want to achieve with stacking, statistics and aligning.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I combine multiple exposures for action shots?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12233/how-do-i-combine-multiple-exposures-for-action-shots)

Comment: While the suggested duplicate is about "action shots", and your action is simply the tick of a watch-hand, I think the techniques there will completely answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is probably to use "Darker" layer mode if hands are darker than the dial and "Brighter" if it's vice versa.

Given that the images are the same except the second-hand, of course.